# Can some one tell me a good reference to study about java virtual machine?

Tags: java

Can some one tell me a good reference to study about java virtual machine

Answer (score 2):

The best way to know important things on the JVM is the [VM Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html).
You should also look at every JSR related to the JVM such as [JSR-924](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=924), [JSR-202](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=202), [JSR-133](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133), etc.

---

**Resources:**

- [Wikipedia - JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JVM) and [Wikipedia - Java Memory Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model)
- [oracle.com - Clarifications and Amendments to the Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/vmspec/2nd-edition/jvms-clarify.html)